# syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING) in /home/cloudcomadmin/public_html/wp-config.php on line 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a database connection error. in wpconfig file I added 
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true); at the bottom.

Now I get error above.  I think it is just a syntax error.

Can anyone advise

Thanks.

```
<?php/** Enable W3 Total Cache */define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache



/**
 * Multi-site
 *
 */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.cloudcom.ca');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the code as-posted. but if you get "unexpected", then something EARLIER wasn't terminated properly. e.g. a missing `;`, a missed `'` or `"` leaving a string option, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error because PHP see's your starting php tag as bogus--in fact you'd this is treated as if you don't have a starting `<?php` tag.

IF you really must add code on the same line as your PHP script declaration tag, put a  space between your comment and the `<?php` tag:

```
 <?php /** Enable W3 Total Cache */define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache
```